# Sampling Oscillators for Lookup Table

Tags: sampling, analog, oscillator

I have couple of analog synthesizers and I want to turn their oscillators into code. I've been reading about how to do it for a while and making a lookup table seems just right for me. I've been modeling some linear/nonlinear effect units, but I'm new to modeling synthesizers, so at this point, there is a great possibility of me making wrong assumptions, please feel free to correct them.

Edit: My question is, Let's say for a Moog Little Phatty, In which position should I keep the ADSR envelope knobs in the range of 1 to 10 while taking samples? And in which state(s)(2', 4', 8', 16')of octave switch should I take samples?